# Get homebrew to run a script after 'brew install x' or 'brew uninstall x'

Tags: bash, macos, shell, sh, homebrew

I want to automate having a file that tracks all my installed brew packages.

I can do this manually with `brew list > somefile`, how ever I want this process to be automated.

Is there a way to run a script automatically after running `brew install` or `brew uninstall`?

Or is there a better way of doing this I'm overlooking?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can create functions to run the `brew install` or `brew uninstall` and add on whatever else you'd like to run.

```
function bi() {
  brew install $@
  brew list > somefile
}

function bu() {
  brew uninstall $@
  brew list > somefile
}
```

Then instead of running `brew install [package]` or `brew uninstall [package]` you just run `bi [package]` or `bu [package]` and your `somefile` file will always have an up-to-date list of installed packages.

You'll need to add these functions to one of your startup files: `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`, so they will be available with each new bash session.